# Making a model of a transformer

Tags: transformer, short-circuit, coil, modeling, test-equipment

According to this [link](http://www.eecs.ucf.edu/~tomwu/course/eel4205/notes/07%20Nonideal%20Transformer.pdf), the equivelent circuit diagram of a transformer (seen from the secondary side) looks like:

[image]

Now, I want to find the values of the following constants:

$$R_p,X_p,R_c,X_m,R_s,X_s\tag1$$

So, my idea was to set \$V_p=10\sin(2\pi ft)\$ and \$n=N_p/N_s=1\$. Now I vary the input frequency and I measure a RMS current trough the load resistor that I put in series with \$X_s\$ (at the output). If I do that for six different input frequencies I can solve for the six constants in \$(1)\$.

> Can I use that method of finding all the constants that I described in \$(1)\$?

Comment: Just FYI, number of measurements != number of parameters that you can estimate.

Answer (score 1):

The core losses Rc are quite strongly frequency dependent and level dependent, so varying the frequency will lead to mis-modelling of all the lossy R terms. I would expect the system of 6 equation to be quite ill-conditioned, so very sensitive to small reading errors.

Normally, we estimate Rp and Rs from DC measurements. We estimate Lp from an open circuit measurement and Lm from a short circuit measurement, as described in the rest of the paper you've linked.